# Our team finally won the bronze!

Tags: riddle, knowledge, science

Our team has really made it. We managed to win the bronze despite finishing on the 16th place.

While our oldest member is only sixteen, the youngest of us is over one hundred (and we expect him to live more).

Despite many people describe us as toxic ones, we are so friendly that we can communicate with six at once! The only exception is the skinniest of us, he usually cannot speak with more than two at a time.

We are six, but you all need help of the eighth of us (so strongly that you cannot even live without him).

What are we? What's the name of our team?

Hint (maybe decisive):

> Before finishing 16th, we took 6th place in the group stage (we participated in Group A).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your team is called

> [The Chalcogens](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Descriptive_Chemistry/Elements_Organized_by_Block/2_p-Block_Elements/Group_16%3A_The_Oxygen_Family_(The_Chalcogens)/1Group_16%3A_General_Properties_and_Reactions)

You win the bronze because

> If the noble gasses are in first place, you are in third

Your members

> Include element 16, Sulfur, which is oldest because it is found as a mineral in nature without much work, and your youngest is element 102, which is Nobelium

You speak by

> Forming bonds. Your members can bond with six other elements, other than Oxygen which can form two bonds.

We all need

> Element 8, Oxygen, in order to live

Comment: Oops, thanks for catching that missing spoiler tag @stiv

Comment: Great! However, some clues have different intended explanations, namely rot13("punypbtraf" pna or yvgrenyyl genafyngrq nf "oebamr-znxvat") and rot13("byqrfg" naq "lbhatrfg" npghnyyl zrna gur beqre bs qvfpbirel, naq gur "lbhatrfg" bs gurz vf yvirezbevhz, ryrzrag 116 (fb "yvir zber" nf nyfb yvxr n uvag)). Despite that, your explanations may be even better!

Comment: @trolley813 I am sorry, what are you talking about?

Comment: @DeepakMS rot13 is a way to encode words by "rotating" the letters 13 spaces forwards. Applying it a second time decodes the message so it's an easy way to give spoilers in comments. You can go to rot13.com for example to decode the hidden hints in trolley's comment.